# What does three steps of Vamana avataar symbolize?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, symbolism, vamana

I very well understand the story of Bali and Vamana but as a common man I would like to understand what exactly does three steps of Vamana (Vishnu avataar) symbolize?

Any commentaries on this topic by a renowned spiritual personality will be acceptable.

Comment: I found the answer finally! It is in sb 8.19.24.

Answer (score 2):

**Matsya Purana- Chapter 260 - Shloka 36**  gives us the  basic meaning of this three steps of Vamana as "Pervading all the universe" .

> तथा त्रिविक्रमं वक्ष्ये ब्रह्माण्डक्रमणोल्बणम्। 
>  पादपार्श्वे तथा
>   बाहुमुपरिष्टात् प्रकल्पयेत् ।। 260.36||
>
> Now about the Vamana form of lord striding the three worlds , as if
>   pervading all the universe .

---

Shri Adi Shankaracharya in his [**Vishnu  Sahasranama  Bhasya name 530**](https://archive.org/details/Vishnu.Sahasranama.with.the.Bhasya.of.Sankaracharya/page/n115)  - i.e. Trivikrama is also explaning the above symbolism behind these three steps of dwarf avatara Vamana.

> 530 - Trivikrama -The three-stepped
>
> Vyakhya - The three steps were in the three worlds. The shruti (
>   Tai.Br. 2.4.6) says :" He stepped (the three worlds ) by his three
>   steps" ; or has walked over the three worlds. The Harivamsha (279-80)
>   says : The sages have named the three worlds as tri ; and as you
>   walked them all thrice you are named Tri (vi) krama. .

---

According to [**Pancharatra**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/trivikrama) tradition of Vaishnavism  the three steps of Vamana symbolise that  Vamana (Vishnu) had gone beyond the three vedas.  The Wisdom Library page in its meaning of Trivikrama is explaning this with the ref. of  **commentary of Parashara Bhatta** as follows.

> These Vibhavas (eg., Trivikrama) represent the third of the five-fold
>   manifestation of the Supreme Consciousness the Pāñcarātrins believe
>   in. Note: The name Trivikrama is given to Vāmana who grew up and took
>   three strides (krama). Parāśarabhaṭṭa Viṣṇusahasranāma vyākhyā on Name
>   533. gives a different interpreation by quoting a passage the source of which is not known. This means that Viṣṇu had passed through all
>   the three Vedas or had gone beyond them. The root kram means to walk
>   over, cross over. The word Vikrama cannot therefore mean studying the
>   three Vedas but has gone beyond them, prominent in them.